# how to click somewhere on page with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am doing web scraping with BeautifulSoup.I want to scrape comments from steam profiles.But I have a problem I cant change the current page after I am done with first comment page because comment page is not related to URL so cant control it with URL .

Answer (score 1):

BeautifulSoup doesn't really handle that. For what you describe, you need to look into a browser automation tool, like [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) for example.